# Python: Check if set of 2D points contain at least 2 horizontal lines

Tags: python

given is a numpy array of 2D (x,y) points (integers). E.g.:

```
points = np.array([[3,3],[5,4],[1,6],[10,6],[100,100]])
```

I want to check:

Does the data build at least two horizontal lines? A horizontal line is defined as a set of 2D points with a MAXIMUM y-difference of 1 and a MINIMUM x-difference of 1. Two horizontal lines must have different y-coordinates.

The output should be a boolean: True if the set contains two horizontal lines, False if not. The above mentioned array should output True. One line is formed by (3,3) and (5,4) and the other horizontal line is formed by (1,6) and (10,6).

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you please post sample input data, and expected output data. Also, please clarify whether you're looking for two **non-overlapping** lines

Comment: I hope a clarified that example. Due to the fact that they are horizontal and must have a gap in y-coordinates of minimum 1, they cannot be overlapping!?

Comment: A natural place to start is to create a dictionary which is keyed by the y-coordinates. The values which go with key `k` can be the set of points which have y-coordinate `k` or `k-1` or `k+1`.  This dictionary (which can be constructed in `O(n)` should contain all of the needed information.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way of comparison! (Maybe it's the worst - comparing every point with every point (O = n*n) ) You should check another algorithms.

=> [DEMO](https://repl.it/@JakubUjwary/HurtfulRoyalNotification#main.py)

```
import numpy as np

points = np.array([[3,3],[5,4],[1,6],[10,6],[100,100]])

def checkIfLineInArray(array):
  result = 0
  for p1 in points:
      for p2 in points:
          if(p1[0]==p2[0] and p1[1]==p2[1]):
              #same point we want skip
              continue
          
          if(((p2[1]-1) < p1[1] < (p2[1]+1))):
              print('there is horizontal line between this points')
              print(p1,p2)
              result = 1
  return result

checkIfLineInArray(points)
```

Comment or delete print's from this function as You need : )